# Browser Authentication Prompt After Server Restart

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, load-balancing, authentication, windows-authentication

Details

We have an internal website. The authentication mode is windows hence it takes windows logins. It is served from two windows servers running Windows Server 2008 R2. And are connected with Network Load Balancer (Request Handling - Round Robin).

Every month there is a routine patching on the servers which leads to restart of the server (not at the same time).

When restart occurs, we get Authentication prompts and it continues to give the prompt even after giving a right credentials. Popup wont go.. plain and simple.

Now after few hours, it gets normal.

I am not sure what happens.

We have checked everything. IISlogs, Network Monitor Log, Load balancer log but no help as they are equal to the other server which works fine.

---

One important thing to consider here is that the server that is causing problem, the website is hosted under the default website of iis but in case of the server that works fine, its a virtual directory.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to make sure the web site is listed as an Local Intranet security zone? In the browser go to **Tools** > **Internet Options** > **Security** tab > **Local Intranet** and add it to the **Site** list.

This can be caused with the way the browser will send credentials to the web site. It will send the credentials for Intranet web sites, but not others.

Comment: This is not a problem. The above problem is not occuring in just my machine. more than 200k users are affected in 28 locations.